# Show Search Results from 2 database fields

Tags: php, html, database, search

I have a search function that searches a database then displays the results in PHP/HTML.

I am trying to show the results from 2 fields not just one...

Here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '%$name%'") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
```

I am trying to add

```
FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '%$name%' AND `prodID` LIKE '%$name%'
```

However this doesn't seem to be working? I do not get an error, just no results show?

Comment: `prodID` should be an integer whereas `name` should be a string. So, it should not match obviously.

Comment: Your query is absolutely correct, I checked. But make sure- your query will fetch the results if of the conditions are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using OR:

```
FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '%$name%' OR `prodID` LIKE '%$name%'
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah,`$name` should be concatenated when passing directly into an query,
 because it will search $name in database,not the value assigned for `$name`
 Try the below query
`$name = 'search_value';` 
`...`
 `SELECT * FROM`products`WHERE`prodname`LIKE '%'".$name."'%' OR`prodID`LIKE '%'".$name."'%'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE `prodname` LIKE '%".$name."%'") or die('Error: Line 519 (' . mysql_error() . ')');
```